# Is the sentence correct and also can someone let me know the correct tense

Tags: tense

- It was supposed to be released this year
- It was supposed to get released this year

Also *supposed* is past tense but the word "released" is also used as past. Why is that? The event didn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence *released* is [past participle adjective](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/participle-adjectives.html). So there is no contradiction between tenses in this example.